# On the Wednesdays of September Vs. On September Wednedays

Tags: word-order, syntax

Which is the correct one:

> - On the Wednesdays of September, I used to go to the cinema with my dad.
> - On September Wednesdays, I used to go to the cinema with my dad.

Answer (score 5):

Neither one sounds natural. A more natural wording would be *On Wednesdays in September, I used to go to the cinema with my dad.*

Comment: Even "on Wednesdays" sounds a bit stilted in this usage. I would suggest *"Each Wednesday in September..."* as the most natural.

Comment: I'd say that  each vs. on is really a matter of taste and meaning.  Each emphasizes that is was every single Wednesday. On could mean every Wednesday, or it could mean some or most Wednesdays.

Answer (score 3):

> On September Wednesdays

would be understood, but I think a native speaker would more likely use *in*:

Also, when referring to a set of recurring days of the week (Sundays, Mondays, etc.), one does not ordinarily use the definite article.

> On Wednesdays in September, I used to go to the cinema with my dad.

Answer (score 1):

Both OP's versions are completely unacceptable. In principle there's nothing inherently incorrect about the suggested alternative *on Wednesdays in September*, but it doesn't sound like very natural phrasing to me (I feel the way it emphasises plural *Wednesdays* is "odd" in this context). I suggest something like...

> In September I used to go to the cinema with my dad on Wednesday.

It's grammatically optional whether you pluralise *Wednesday* there. I tend to prefer the singular because we're not actually talking about very many trips to the cinema in total, and we're already stretching the idiomatic *"I used to"* with such a small number of occurrences. Using the singular dayname seems to me to help "balance" the utterance. But that's really just a personal stylistic preference.

Comment: US v UK?  Wednesdays in September sounds perfectly natural to me.

Comment: @Dan Neely: Well, I did say there's nothing "inherently incorrect" about it. But I suggest it's quite likely you've never actually come across that exact sequence of three words in *any* context - let alone one that also has ***used to*** meaning *was in the habit of*. I just don't think "September Wednesdays" or "Wednesdays in September" are a particularly recognisable "type of Wednesday" that you would naturally reference in the context of describing such a short-lived "habitual action". It's not like, say, *winter evenings*.